# How can I retrieve 6 digits from within my concatenated numbers?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of numbers which are separated by hyphens. The format and length is always the same. Example:

65-09-27-542400-6147

I want to retrieve the 6 digits from after the third hyphen. Using the data in the above example, the result is:

542400

My formula can only retrieve the numbers from after the first hyphen. Using above example, this will be 09:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("-*-",A1)+1,SEARCH("-",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","^",1))-SEARCH("-*-",A1)-1),"")
```

How can I adjust my current formula to retrieve the 6 digits after the third hyphen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and most efficient is to use the `MID` function if they are all the exact format:

```
=mid(A1,10,6)
```

Comment: This was the best answer as it doesn't display an error when the data is missing, and doesn't lose the 0 due to cell formatting .

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
=regexextract(A1,"\d{6}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPLIT()` function.

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"-")),4)
```

[image]

Comment: `SPLIT` Function GOOGLE SHEET --> Thank you @Harun24HR Bhaia !!!